# What is the total number of flags shown on admin?filter=all?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, flags

On https://drupal.stackexchange.com/admin?filter=all, I read the following:

> 3.3k flags, average handling time 19 hours 8 minutes

Checking the number of flags from all the moderators (including Community Coordinators), I get a total of 1,653.
Between the actually elected moderators, there isn't a temporary moderator; between the Community Coordinators, there isn't Dori. Still, the difference between the 3.3k flags shown in the summary, and the 1,653 flags I get as sum is too high. It doesn't seem quite possible that  two users handled the 1,647 flags missing from the count.

How can the difference be explained?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The remaining are comment flags.

Comment: Aren't those already included, in the numbers I added?

Comment: No. It adds to the total count, but not an individual's count.